# Import 3D curves without affecting their curvature

Tags: bezier-curves, obj

I have created a series of **curves in Rhino**. I also have a joined version of them. Obviously, the curvature of each individual curve matches its corresponding section on the joined curve as shown below:

[image]

I saved the file as **OBJ in Blender**, then import it into Blender. But the imported curves no longer match. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I imported the OBJ back into Rhino and everything is fine. What should I do to have the exact same curvature when I import the curves into Blender?